# how to load application-context.xml using @ContextConfiguration annotation

Tags: java, spring, junit4

My project structure is as below:

```
src/main/java -> contains java classes  
src/main/resources/spring/context/application-context.xml  
src/test/java -> contains J-unit test
```

I would like to use @ContextConfiguration annotation to load my application-context.xml

How can I load this file and how can I make sure that all beans are loaded?
I tried it using classpath and file. But nothing works for me. 
I am confused when to use classpath and file. Some one please help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`@ContextConfiguration("classpath:/spring/context/application-context.xml")` should work.

In conventional Maven project layout, `src/main/resources` contains classpath resources, therefore you should use `classpath:` or no prefix at all, because `classpath:` should be a default one in this case.

If it still doesn't work, perhaps something is wrong with your project configuration and files from `src/main/resources` doesn't appear in the classpath.

If context loads successfully, all beans in it should be loaded as well, otherwise context will fail to load.

Comment: What are the dependencies required for spring to look for this annotation?

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
ApplicationContext APPLICATION_CONTEXT = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/spring/context/application-context.xml");
```

If it does not work, try putting `application-context.xml` directly in `src/main/resources` and then load it with

```
ApplicationContext APPLICATION_CONTEXT = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml");
```